# Is it possible to use AppCenter Push notifications without GCM?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have purposely built Android mobile phone without Google Play or any of the Google services installed. I'm building Xamarin.Forms mobile app and need to show Push notification. I'm trying to do this using AppCenter, I can see that the device has been registered on Analytics, but no push messages are showing up. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

> Google announced it is migrating from the Google Cloud Messaging (GSM) platform to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). For Android developers, the Firebase SDK is required to use Push Notifications. For additional information, please refer to the SDK migration guide.

and

> Only devices with the Google Play Store application or emulators using Google APIs images can receive notifications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/android

You need FCM (GCM is deprecated)

Comment: So I guess the answer is no then. Looking at the second quote - these devices I'm using does not have Google Play Store installed. What is considered Google API's emulator?

Comment: Emulators using Googles' API images. What part do you not understand?